# Как в selenium кликнуть по кнопке AJAX

Tags: c#, selenium

Нужно  написать тест для отработки кликов по кнопкам на сайте.

Есть несколько проблем:

1. Заведомо неизвестный номер оффера. Может быть `Offer6552`, а следующий `Offer7592`. По CSS селектору кликнуть не получается.
2. Также генерируются CSS класс самой кнопки, он зависит от цвета самой кнопки и заранее не возможно предсказать CSS какого цвета сгенерируется.

Есть ли некий способ искать в Selenium по заведомо известной части CSS селектора как в случае `Browser.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText())`;

```css
<button onclick="AjaxLoader('Offer6552', 'func', 'new_follow','&amp;offer=6552&amp;streamer=ssjsk8');" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"  style="border: 1px solid #000;">

Follow &nbsp;(+32 <i class="fa fa-database" title="Credits"></i>)

</button>
```